# I need to write a batch file to set the system environmental variables ,

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch file to set the system environmental variables as shown below

```
WRD_WF_ROOT=e:\wrd_ntl_v23
WRD_Wld_ROOT=e:\wrd_ntl_v23
```

and I need to run the script for 250 users .

Comment: So what is your problem then?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for setx, it is like a normal set but it survives after your computer restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean non-volatile system wide variables, if that is the case, you can call reg.exe and add your entries to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (reg.exe is available by default on WinXP+)

To execute things on remote machines, [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) is your friend.